# can i use 'this' operator in express-handlebars as array index in the same express-handlebars?

Tags: express, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

```
{{@root.comments.[this.[0]].[0]._id}}
```

> Error: Parse error on line 96:
>   ...t.comments.[this.[0]].[0]._id}}:5:31)
>       at prog (/home/nkhil/Nikhil/test-handlebar/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/runtime.js:221:12)
>       at execIteration (/home/nkhil/Nikhil/test-handlebar/node_modules/handlebars/dist/cjs/handlebars/helpers/each.js:51:19)

---

### can anybody please help me ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: consider adding the complete information about the origin of the error.

Comment: can you provide the complete code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't do that. It's not a valid expression in handlebars. Try to save the state instead of using this operator.